# where to find the origing category.php file in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

Hi I'm new to wordpress I have been working on a theme I would like to have the original category.php file that needs to get added on the theme? I have tried to copy a category.php file from a theme that was created on the core of wordpress but the body is missing, where can I find the original category.php file template that will be used by wordpress when it is not being defined on my theme?

version: wordpress 3.5.1

Comment: Make your own, as theme files are specific to the theme, or you can copy the twentytwelve theme's file, which is in your themes folder.

Answer (score 1):

As templates are going to have theme specific markup, you'll need to make revisions to any file that you plan on copying over if you want the page to work with your theme.

A simpler solution is to copy your page.php file and replace your post loop with that of the categories loop.  This will allow you to easily maintain your site's design without having to rework any markup and can be accomplished pretty quickly by copy/pasting a category loop snippet.

A great starting place to see how these loops are structured is the WP twentytwelve theme found here: http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentytwelve

Much greater documentation can also be found in the codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Answer (score 0):

Template files are stored in:

```
/wp-content/themes/<theme_name>/
```

You can copy the category template from a theme, but then it wouldn't look like it's a part of your theme though and might be badly styled because of missing CSS rules.